# Direct URL to open popup?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page which contains a jQuery player.

Upon entering the page url in the address bar, How can i make the page appear in a popup with set dimensions?

[Example](http://www.di.fm/play/trance)

- Warning: music is played in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This javascript example should work just put in the link you want to be opened.

```
<a href="http://www.learningmovabletype.com/about2.php" onclick="window.open('http://www.learningmovabletype.com/about2.php','popup','width=600,height=700,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=50,top=0'); return false">About</a>
```

Example taken from [here](http://www.learningmovabletype.com/a/000326popup_window/).

If you want your popup to open automatically from direct access to a specific link; you could try to use onLoad to run a java function as soon as your html body loads.. Ex:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function my_function(){
window.open('http://www.example.com/about2.php','popup','width=600,height=700,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=50,top=0');
}
<script>
<body onLoad='my_function()'>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want a unique popup for each page loaded you need to include a parameter in your link Ex: mylink.php?popid=123 Then use $_GET to get that value...

```
<?php
$popid = $_GET['popid'];
?>
```

Then in your java-script function you can call a specific link as in.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function my_function(){
 var link = <?php echo $popid; ?>;
window.open('http://www.example.com/player.php?popid=<?php echo $popid; ?> ','popup','width=600,height=700,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=50,top=0');
    }
    <script>
```

Comment: Thanx for the code...i need the page to open automatically as a popup..just like if you go to stackoverflow.com and it will be opened in a popup.

Comment: @TonalDev: So do you mean when people are redirected to a new page you want them to open this popup? Not on a page they just click a link and the pop-up opens?

Comment: Almost accurate, i need someone to enter: www.example.com/player...and that will auto open a popup with the player.

Comment: Oh; I don't think you can do a direct link open because it requires a java call but I know what java function I think could do the trick. I will update my answer.

Comment: 'JavaScript'...not 'Java'

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse: Sigh, yes; if you noticed I also answered within 60 seconds of his question... I shortened phrases to keep to the point and respond quickly. The code above is obviously java-script. Please try to keep comments within StackOverflow community comment guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment